# How to fetch a file from a windows node with Ansible

Tags: windows, ansible, fetch

I would like to fetch a file (info.txt) that has been created on a windows node through ansible. I have tried to use the fetch module (which works for me on a linux node), which seems not to work on a windows client. Here is the relevant code:

```
task:
  -name: Fetch a info file
   fetch: src=C:\info.txt dest=/home/user flat=yes
```

I get no error but the file is not fetched. I run ubuntu on my local machine. Am I doing something wrong? thanks

Here is the output of the playbook run with -vvv option on:

```
If (Test-Path -PathType Leaf "C:\info.txt")
{
$sp = new-object -TypeName   System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider;
$fp = [System.IO.File]::Open("C:\info.txt[System.IO.Filemode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read);
[System.BitConverter]::ToString($sp.ComputeHash($fp)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
$fp.Dispose();
}
ElseIf (Test-Path -PathType Container "C:\info.txt")
{
Write-Host "3";
}
Else 
{
Write-Host "1";
} 
<192.168.122.123> FETCH "C:\info.txt" TO "/home/diego/work/ansible_win/ex1"
```

changed: [win1] => {"changed": true, "checksum": null, "dest": "/home/diego/work/ansible_win/ex1", "invocation": {"module_args": {"dest": "/home/diego/work/ansible_win/ex1", "flat": "yes", "src": "C:/info.txt"}, "module_name": "fetch"}, "md5sum": null, "remote_checksum": "9664e0d22d3e184eb206d60af29e340f620092d0", "remote_md5sum": null}

Comment: I think you'll need to change your `src` backslash to a forward slash, e.g. `C:/info.txt`.

Comment: Tried, that does't make any difference..

Comment: What version of ansible?

Comment: Can you add the `-vvv` switch when running your playbook and paste the logging output into your question?

Comment: Hmmm....I'm running 1.9.4, but get the same behaviour. It looks like it's copied the file but nada in my home directory :/

Comment: Yes, that is what I get too

Comment: I think this is a bug. One thing I notice is that in 1.9.4, if I don't have `validate_checksum=no` set then I get a checksum error, presumably because there is nothing written locally. I also noticed that if I `export ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1` ansible doesn't create a remote script file, but strangely if I set `src` to an non-existing filename it does. There's defo something shonky going on here.

Comment: Certainly works ok grabbing a file from another Linux box for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104036/discussion-between-diegus-and-kev).

Comment: uhm, no news about this ? in some days i will need to do this, (fetch from windows boxes)

Comment: @YonsySolis It works for me now, look at the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works for me with the following code:

```
task:
  - name: Fetch a info file
    fetch: src=C:/info.txt dest=/home/user/info.txt flat=yes
```

Compare to the previous code I have changed the "windows" backslash into a slash and added the name of the file at the end of the `dest` path.

Comment: For further insight into why this works, when `fetch` sees a `dest` that doesn't end in a `/`, it tries to create a file with the exact name it sees in `dest`.  Since this fliename is (presumably) already in use by a directory, the file cannot be retrieved.  Specifying the full file name, as above, or adding a trailing `/`, will let `fetch` create the file as expected.  Replacing the `\ ` in `src` very likely had little effect.